# pgfplots different ticklength for each axis

Tags: pgfplots

Is there an easy way to have different tick length for the X and Y axis? While a lot of the tick formating commands have `x` and `y` versions to effect only the corresponding axis, I can't find an axis specific version of `major tick length`. In particular `xaxis tickstyle={major tick length=2pt}` yields `unknown key /tikz/major tick`length.

So far the only solution I can think of is two `scale only axis`, one for the X ticks and one for the y ticks, however copying all axis formating (i.e. min/max) up to date between axis is cumbersome. If this is the only option is ther an easy way to inherit all options from another axis?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
      tick align=outside,
      xtick={1,6},
      xticklabels={a,b},
      ytick={0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
      major tick length=1ex%,
%      x major tick length=0ex
    ]
        \addplot  plot coordinates {
            (1,0.5)     
            (6,1)
        };
    \end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just declare the x ticks to be extra, and then modify the style of these extra ticks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
      tick align=outside,
      xtick=\empty,
      extra x ticks={1,6},
      extra x tick style={major tick length=2pt,blue},
      ytick={0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
      major tick length=1ex%,
    ]
        \addplot  plot coordinates {
            (1,0.5)     
            (6,1)
        };
    \end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this answers the question, I curious about a few more things: Why doesn't `xtick style={major tick length=2pt}` work? (unkonwn key `major tick length`)? And what to do if one axis uses `xtick=data` and `ytick` is the empty list (i.e. default generated), how could I transform one of thos to `extra xticks`?

Comment: @ted I was also wondering why `xtick style={major tick length=2pt}` won't work. I guess you'd need to ask this question Christian Feuersänger. And the second part I do not understand: if ytick is the empty list, then there is only one style to modify. But you can always use [percusse's nice trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168641/121799) to get the list of "extra" ticks from the data.

Comment: If the ticks list is not specified pgfplots autogenerates some ticks. But if `extra x ticks` is empty there won't be ticks. So I would not be sure which values to put into `extra y ticks` (well I could render, note the values autogenerated and use those). The link to percusse is nice. Thanks for the help

Comment: I created a [ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/207/) for Christian Feuersaenger.

Comment: @ted, @marmot: the error message complains about an unknown key `/tikz/major tick length`, here the `/tikz/` is the important hint. Using the full path for the key (`xtick style={/pgfplots/major tick length=2pt}`) works.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! (Still strange that for `extra x tick style` one doesn't need that...)

Comment: @Mike: Thanks, I guess that would be an answer in its own right. I edited the answer so that your solution gets higher visibility.

Comment: @Mike since the edit was rejected, care to make your comment in an answer for higher visibility?